# Есть ли стандарт на обмен сообщениями между сервером и клиентом?

Tags: javascript, php, архитектура, клиент-сервер, стандарт

Всем привет!
На стороне клиента пользователь заполняет форму с данными.
Сервер получает данные формы в виде строки:
ключ10`^=`значение10`^;`ключ11`^=`значение11`^;`ключ12`^=`значение12
`^&`
ключ20`^=`значение20`^;`ключ21`^=`значение21`^;`ключ22`^=`значение22

...

Где нулевые ключи и значения - id и исходное состояние родительских элементов,
остальные ключи и значения - id и исходные состояния дочерних элементов.
Сервер выдаёт аналогичный ответ с уже изменёнными состояниями.
Естественно, разделители `^=`, `^;`, `^&` придумал их головы)))

В общем-то вопрос:
1. есть ли какой-либо стандарт какие разделители использовать при обмене информации между клиентом и сервером и вообще строчными элементами? Или каждый производитель ПО использует, что ему хочется?
2. И ещё: есть ли какой-либо общепринятый стандарт или спецификация на оформление информации, которой обмениваются клиент и сервер?

Comment: JavaScript Object Notation

Comment: а, что-то я стормозил - можно представить эти данные как объект в json и потом преобразовать нативными функциями в объект php. Спасибо! А каких-либо ещё вариантов нету?

Comment: еще - eXtensible Markup Language

Comment: `multipart/form-data`, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: Можно использовать protobuf, большой плюс в том, что все данные строго типизированные в отличии JSON или XML

Comment: @ЕвгенийГаврилов, только он бинарный, в отличие от JSON и XML

Comment: смешно, но поиск ответа на этот вопрос неожиданно привёл меня к другому вопросу xD

Answer (score 0):

Ответы на вопросы:
1. Стандартов именно на разделители нет.
2. Есть множество форматов данных. Самый актуальный для связки js-php - json. нативный формат js и php имеет стандартные средства для его обработки с 5ой версии. С 7ой - средства переписаны и улучшены.
Есть случаи когда лучше писать использовать свой формат обмена данными. Однако данная тема выходит за рамки вопроса.